# How to get a single array with no-repeated items, with the sum of their value(s). ordered desc

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, lodash

If I have the following Array:

```
var myArray = [
 {sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 50}},
 {sa86w:{id:'sa86w', name: 'Amy', value: 40}},
 {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 30}},
 {sa74x:{id:'sa74x', name: 'John', value: 20}},
 {sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 10}},
 {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 15}},
]
```

What is the best one to get a single array with no-repeated items, with the sum of their value(s) and ordered by descending value for all the repeated items from another array using **lodash**?

Te expected result should be something like this:

```
result = [{sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 60}},
 {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 45}},
 {sa86w:{id:'sa86w', name: 'Amy', value: 40}},
 {sa74x:{id:'sa74x', name: 'John', value: 20}}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are a bunch of ways to do it. Off the top of my head, I would use `reduce` to convert your array of objects into one object with summed values. Using `chain` to combine with some other lodash methods for ordering and transforming, it would look like this:

```
const result = _.chain(myArray)
  .map(person => _.values(person))
  .flatten()
  .reduce((summed, person) => {
    if (!summed[person.id]) {
      summed[person.id] = person
    } else {
      summed[person.id].value += person.value
    }
    return summed
  }, {})
  .values()
  .orderBy(['value'], ['desc'])
  .map(person => ({ [person.id]: person }))
  .value()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) to combine all objects into a single object. Since `_.mergeWith` is recursive, the inner properties will be merged as well, and we can use this to sum the `value` property. Afterwards, we convert the object back to an array using [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map):

```js
const myArray = [{"sa67g":{"id":"sa67g","name":"Leo","value":50}},{"sa86w":{"id":"sa86w","name":"Amy","value":40}},{"sa33p":{"id":"sa33p","name":"Alex","value":30}},{"sa74x":{"id":"sa74x","name":"John","value":20}},{"sa67g":{"id":"sa67g","name":"Leo","value":10}},{"sa33p":{"id":"sa33p","name":"Alex","value":15}}];

const result = _.map(
  // merge all objects into a single object, and sum the value property
  _.mergeWith({}, ...myArray, (objValue = 0, srcValue = 0, key) => key === 'value' ? objValue + srcValue : undefined),
  // split back into an array of objects
  (v, k) => ({ [k]: v })
)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Easily, the most elegant solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easiest way to filter out single values would be to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Use it to get a set of unique keys.
2. Create the desired object by iterating the keys and calculating the sums.

Answer (score 0):

Using native methods and assuming es8 support:

```js
var myArray = [
 {sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 50}},
 {sa86w:{id:'sa86w', name: 'Amy', value: 40}},
 {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 30}},
 {sa74x:{id:'sa74x', name: 'John', value: 20}},
 {sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 10}},
 {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 15}},
]

var tmp = myArray.map(o => Object.values(o)[0])
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    const obj = a[c.name]
    if (obj) {
      obj.id = c.id > obj.id ? c.id : obj.id;// set highest id
      obj.value += c.value; //increment vlues
    } else {
      a[c.name] = Object.assign({},c);
    }
    return a;
  }, {});

var res = Object.values(tmp)
  .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
  .map(o => ({[o.id]:o }))
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a step by step approach and take the resutl for the next function with a pipe.

```js
var array = [{ sa67g: { id: 'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 50 } }, { sa86w: { id: 'sa86w', name: 'Amy', value: 40 } }, { sa33p: { id: 'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 30 } }, { sa74x: { id: 'sa74x', name: 'John', value: 20 } }, { sa67g: { id: 'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 10 } }, { sa33p: { id: 'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 15 } }],
    pipe =  (...fn) => arg => fn.reduce((x, f) => f(x), arg),
    objects = array => array.map(o => Object.assign({}, Object.values(o)[0])),
    sum = array => array.reduce((m, o) => {
        if (m.has(o.id)) {
            m.get(o.id).value += o.value;
        } else {
            m.set(o.id, o);
        }
        return m;
    }, new Map),
    values = map => Array.from(map.values()),
    sort = array => array.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value),
    map = array => array.map(o => ({ [o.id]: o })),
    path = pipe(objects, sum, values, sort, map),
    result = path(array);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object properties should never be a value (ie, a *key* or *id*) – to create a key-value association, use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

```js
const concat = ({ id: id1, name: name1, value: v1 }, { id: id2, name: name2, value: v2 }) =>
  ({ id: id1, name: name1, value: v1 + v2 })

const main = xs =>
  xs.map (x => Object.entries (x) [ 0 ])
    .reduce ((acc, [ key, value ]) =>
      acc.has (key)
        ? acc.set (key, concat (value, acc.get (key)))
        : acc.set (key, value), new Map)

const myArray =
  [ {sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 50}}
  , {sa86w:{id:'sa86w', name: 'Amy', value: 40}}
  , {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 30}}
  , {sa74x:{id:'sa74x', name: 'John', value: 20}}
  , {sa67g:{id:'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 10}}
  , {sa33p:{id:'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 15}}
  ]

console.log (main (myArray))
// => Map {
//   'sa67g' => { id: 'sa67g', name: 'Leo', value: 60 },
//   'sa86w' => { id: 'sa86w', name: 'Amy', value: 40 },
//   'sa33p' => { id: 'sa33p', name: 'Alex', value: 45 },
//   'sa74x' => { id: 'sa74x', name: 'John', value: 20 } }
```

If you want to convert the Map back to an object, you can use this

```
const mapToObject = m =>
  Array.from(m.entries ()).reduce ((acc, [ k, v ]) =>
    Object.assign (acc, { [ k ]: v }), {})
```